# How to encode U+FFFD in order to do a replace?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, special-characters

In a text file I obtain from a source I do not control, and which text content changes periodically and I have to compensate by re-downloading and processing, the char U+FFFD occurs frequently (but not always) when what is meant is the single quote or ' character.

How can I encode a replace operation so as to replace the U+FFFD with an actual single-quote in C#. I envision something like:

```
string s = s.Replace("U+FFFD", "'");
```

Clearly I should use the overload that deals with char, but I am not sure how to encode the U+FFFD, or for that matter, the single quote!

Comment: Incidentally, this is a hallmark of bad charset wrangling (possibly on the server side).  [U+FFFD is the `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Comment: That is likely true, but nothing I can do anything about.  All I do is download it as a text file, and have to deal with what it looks like.

Comment: you're replacing string "U+FFFD" just like any other string e.g "foo"

Comment: You are using the char [`U+FFFD` for the wrong purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28168981/632951). The "replacement" char is not meant to do these kind of replacements.

Comment: @Pacerier, if you read the whole question, the replacement character is coming across from a source not under my control -- I just have to deal with it when it arrives.  *I* am not using it.  I am trying to *deal* with it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have to tried to find out the actual binary representation of the single quote characters in the source file? I have a feeling that you (implicitly) interpret the source file as UTF-8 (or similar) while it's actually in a different character encoding. For instance, `\xB4` in ISO-8859-1 also looks like a single quote. I don't know how critical this process is, but relying on error recovery behaviour (in this case, decoding bytes that don't fit in UTF sequences by `U+FFFD`) doesn't sound like a good solution to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string s = s.Replace('\uFFFD','\'');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  Saved me a lot of drudge work this morning!