# PHP: How to encode U+FFFD in order to do a replace?

Tags: php, character-encoding, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to display a data feed on a page. We're experiencing encoding issues with a weird character. For some reason, in the feed there's the `U+FFFD` character. And `htmlentities()` will not escape the character, so I need to replace it manually. (I'm using PHP 5.3)

I've tried the following:

```
$string = str_replace( "\xFFFD",  "_", $string );
$string = str_replace( "\XFFFD",  "_", $string );
$string = str_replace( "\uFFFD",  "_", $string );
$string = str_replace("\x{FFFD}", "_", $string );
$string = str_replace("\X{FFFD}", "_", $string );
$string = str_replace("\P{FFFD}", "_", $string );
$string = str_replace("\p{FFFD}", "_", $string );
```

None of the above work.

After reading this page - http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to compile UTF-8 support into PCRE?

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766778/how-to-encode-ufffd-in-order-to-do-a-replace?rq=1) different language but very similar result

Comment: Also try using the [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) function as str_replace doesn't use regex

Comment: @redolent, Guys, stop [abusing the `U+FFFD` character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766778/how-to-encode-ufffd-in-order-to-do-a-replace#comment44707644_4766778) for what it's **not meant to be**.

Comment: @Pacerier the character was given in the feed we had to parse, so there was no way around it. (Screenshot of the input: https://www.flickr.com/photos/90840058@N04/8249714661/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) instead like this:

```
$string = preg_replace('@\x{FFFD}@u', '_', $string);
```

Answer (score 11):

You should attempt to fix the original problem, `FFFD` (The [unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character)) is not in most cases meant to be a real text character but a sign that something was attempted to be decoded in an UTF encoding but that something was not actually encoded in an UTF encoding. It is an alternative to silently discarding invalid bytes or completely halting the decoding process, either way, if you see it, there was an error.

There is no way to know what the original character was. Especially with your solution, since  you replace the character with `_`, you cannot even know that the original source was decoded incorrectly. You should go back to the source and decode it properly.

Note: It's possible for a source text to use `�` as a literal, normal character, for instance when talking about it, and there is no error then. I am excluding this possibility in my answer.

Comment: Well, "�" *is* a "real" character in itself... :) But yes, I agree that there's some root problem the OP is ignoring. +1

Comment: @deceze well, rather it's not normal text character, but you know what I mean right?

Comment: Well, it *is* a real, normal text character. Just like , ☃ and 風 are real characters. It is simply used in special cases. :)

Comment: @deceze but those are real text characters, if I see `�`, I know there was an error and can't know what the real text character behind it was meant to be unless I decode properly :P

Comment: But I can type it as a normal character: �. ��������. That doesn't mean what I typed here was wrongly decoded. I know what you mean, but it *is* a real character. :P

Comment: @deceze got me there, but at least I recall reading that  it's recommended not to use `�` literally

Comment: Maybe so, unless you want to talk about �. ;)

Comment: @deceze ok read this from unicode.org: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf :P I have confused it with `FFFE` :(

Comment: Good discussion. The problem is that one of the fields (on several entries) I'm importing from an XML document has that character in it. I have tried adjusting the encoding, and I'm sure I'm doing it correctly since the other fields have UTF-8 characters appear correctly.

Comment: @redolent by "has that character in it", do you mean it literally appears in the file? That is, when you do a raw hex dump of the file, you see the bytes `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`?

Comment: Yes, it has exactly `EF BF BD` [(See screenshot)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/90840058@N04/8249714661/in/photostream/lightbox/). The strange part is, other similar parts of the file have a valid UTF-8 character in its place.

Comment: @redolent ah I see. There is then nothing you can do, but judging from the surrounding text it doesn't look like there was literally meant to be the character `�` so it must have been some kind of error in the history of that file.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 '�' is U+EFBFBD

to replace UTF you have to use multi hex char to replace it

xEF xBF xBD

```
$string = str_replace("\xEF\xBF\xBD",'X','My ��� some text');
```